# What's the meaning of called in "called X a slur"?

Tags: meaning

Looked at the definitions of called, but there are a lot of them. The one that seemed to make the most sense was the following definition:

> 11. To designate; label: Nobody calls me a liar.

For example:

> The stranger called him a slur in the street for no reason.

I thought that called in that context meant "shout out and designate someone as X", but maybe I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically correct. The sentence

> The stranger called him a slur in the street for no reason.

Need not indicate that the stranger shouted, although it is not unlikely. Th stranger could have whispered, or spoken quietly. What the stranger did do was say:

> You are an X.

or some similar phrase, where X is some derogatory term, quite likely one indicating membership in some disfavored group, although this is not necessarily implied by the word "slur". It could also be "you are ugly" or some personal characteristic.